# Socket.io give Access-Control-Allow-Origin * over ssl even after proving right ssl key and .crt and even setting origins header properly

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, ssl, cors

I am running php application over apache and using socket.io. I was running application without ssl (http://www.example.com) and running node js on same server on different port (say 3000), it was working fine but after shifting over ssl it gives following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1454332602633-382. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I think I am doing everything required. Please help me point out my mistake to solve this issue. Any guidance will be a great favour for me at this time.

```
var app = require('express')();
var cors  = require('cors')();

app.use(cors);

/*  //Also tried this way to set ORIGINS header
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com");
       next();
    });

*/

var _ = require('underscore');

var http = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/my.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/my.crt'),
       // agent: false,
       // requestCert: true,
       // rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//io.origins("https://www.example.com:*"); // 

io.set('origins', 'https://www.example.com:*')

io.set('match origin protocol', true);

http.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```